# What does the word "kzaar" mean?

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia, exclamations

On a YouTube video I have heard a speaker of American English accent in a gaming context saying the exclamation:

> Kzaaar!

Does someone know what that means and how to spell it correctly?
This is the link to the video [TITANFALL | The Online Gamer](https://youtu.be/BC9lSQtIzG4?t=21), they are just talking about a card game and then the boy says *kzaar* I think my strategy for the game would be the roll....

Comment: If you aren’t sure you are typing it correctly, why do you think we will know what the word was without the link to the video? It might help if you could tell us which game they were talking about and what the context of the exclamation was.

Comment: @ColleenV  this was the video and the right minute : https://youtu.be/BC9lSQtIzG4?t=24 I thought it wasnt allow to link the video here

Comment: You should edit your question to include the link and explain more of what was happening in the video. If English is not your native language, you may want to check out [ell.se]

Comment: I am not familiar with that specific exclamation, but often people involved in role playing type games will use made-up terms from the game worlds. My husband and I [Waaagh!](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Waaagh!) sometimes, and knowing English won’t help you understand it if you don’t know anything about 40K.

Comment: Having watched the video, Kazzar! is simply an interjection - a cry of success and triumph. It has no meaning other than to express those two feelings.

Comment: There's no "r" at the end, given that this is an American speaker.  I'm gonna call this a made up word and spell it "Kazaa!", as a reminder of the now-defunct file-sharing system.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a mispronunciation of [huzzah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huzzah), which is an archaic exclamation of delight, similar to the modern [hooray](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hooray).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we'll never know what the gentleman is truly saying, but my view is that the most likely explanation is that the actor (perhaps prompted by the staff of writers attending to this point) intentionally chose to say "kuzzah," whether or not that exists as a word.

Existing answers stating that the word is "huzzah" or a mispronunciation of the same are overthinking the matter in my opinion. I don't think this actor felt compelled to say a pre-existing and accepted English interjection to express his character's pleasure in the moment. "Kuzzah" here has the effect of "huzzah."  The "k" comes across as fairly intentional.

A comparison that occurs to me is the way some people say "yello" instead of "hello" when they answer the phone.  And by "people," I'm primarily referring to the characters on Seinfeld.

Comment: My brother did that years before Seinfeld

Comment: I agree that it’s reasonable to think it’s a nonsense word/sound. Not everybody speaks straight from the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is Huzzah. I was just reading the Wikipedia article when Barmar posted his answer. The link he provides says:

> ***Huzzah*** (sometimes written ***hazzah***; originally spelled ***huzza*** and pronounced ***huz-ZAY***, n***ow often pronounced as huz-ZĀ***. In most modern varieties of English ***hurrah*** or ***hooray***) is, according to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), "apparently a mere exclamation". The dictionary does not mention any specific derivation. Whatever its origins, it has seen occasional literary use since at least the time of Shakespeare, as the first use was in 1573, according to Merriam-Webster.

Just wanted to give a link for the correct [pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsbFWKcgCLc). It is very similar to the one in your video, with the exception of the first sound [h] which in your video sounds something like [kh]: ***[kha-'za:]***, but I attribute it to the chortling of the person pronouncing it. Sometimes chuckling makes you pronounce certain sounds more strongly, especially that the exclamation seems to burst from his mouth beginning with this sound [kh].